Is there a high-performance way to estimate how much memory a list is taking?
I've got an extension method that accepts an enumerable of generic objects and writes them to a database.
These lists can grow quite large, and I don't have an easy way to predict how big they will become.
At the moment, I just force a bulk write to the database every n number of objects - this allows me to clear up some memory.
However, in some cases (depending on the object), I can easily handle one or two million objects. In other cases, 10,000 objects might be too much to hold in memory.
This can take quite a bit of trial-and-error to estimate a good "batch count", and that number can quickly change depending on what's been added to the objects as development continues.
A possible solution I'm exploring is checking the memory used by the list while looping - if it's, say, over 1GB, then force a write.
I don't care if the size is exactly 1GB, it's OK if it's around that size. If it got to 1.2GB, that's no problem.
However, is there a high-performance way to do this check, and does doing it inside an async method cause any issues?
I've found other posts asking similar questions, but they didn't seem to care about performance and the potentially added complexity of async/tasks.
Here's the method I'm using and trying to optimize (this loop executes tens of millions of times in a typical scenario):
public static async Task<long> DoBulkClickHouseInsertAsync<T>(
    this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source,
    ClickHouseConnection connection,
    Action? afterWrite = null,
    CancellationToken? cancellation = null,
    Func<List<T>, string>? progressMessageFactoryForBatch = null,
    int batchSize = 150000,
    int? countTotal = null,
    IProgressReporter? progress = null,
    string? tableName = null
)
{
    Guard.NotNoText(tableName);
    Guard.NotNull(source);

    List<T> batch = [];

    int countProcessed = 0;

    long rowsWritten = 0;

    await using var enumerator = source.GetAsyncEnumerator();

    var last = !await enumerator.MoveNextAsync();

    // tracking "last" so we know to write all objects
    // to database after the last item finished, even
    // if it hasn't reached the maximum batch size count
    while (!last)
    {
        last = !await enumerator.MoveNextAsync();

        countProcessed++;

        batch.Add(enumerator.Current);

        // Internally, this knows to only execute the
        // passed function arguments once every 500ms
        // Lets the UI know we're still running and
        // estimate how much progress we've made
        progress?.Report(
            () => countProcessed,
            () => countTotal ?? 0, // Count total may not be known if processing an enumerable; this is used to estimate percent complete when available
            () =>
                $"Processing {typeof(T).Name.SplitCamelCase().ToLowerInvariant()}s for next database write batch..."
        );

        // Would like to replace "batch.Count >= batchSize" with
        // an estimate of the "batch" list's memory used
        if (batch.Count >= batchSize || last || cancellation?.IsCancellationRequested == true)
        {
            // Let the UI know we're writing
            progress?.Report(
                () => countProcessed,
                // Count total may not be known if processing an enumerable; this is used to estimate percent complete when available
                () => countTotal ?? 0,
                () =>
                    progressMessageFactoryForBatch is not null
                        ? progressMessageFactoryForBatch(batch)
                        : $"Writing batch with {batch.Count:N0} {typeof(T).Name.SplitCamelCase().ToLowerInvariant()}s to database at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}..."
            );

            List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo> propsOrderedByName =
            [
                .. typeof(T).GetProperties().OrderBy(p => p.Name)
            ];

            // Pass bulkCopy the necessary tableNames and batch size
            using var bulkCopy = new ClickHouseBulkCopy(connection)
            {
                DestinationTableName = $"default.{tableName}",
                ColumnNames =
                [
                    // table names match the object's property names and columns are in order to make things simpler
                    .. propsOrderedByName.Select(p => p.Name)
                ],
                BatchSize = batch.Count
            };

            await bulkCopy.InitAsync();

            // bulkCopy wants the batch object's properties to be type of "object"
            await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(
                batch.ConvertAll(item =>
                    propsOrderedByName
                        .Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null))
                        .Cast<object>()
                        .ToArray()
                )
            );

            rowsWritten = bulkCopy.RowsWritten;

            // Free up used batch memory
            batch.Clear();

            // Optional function that might be used to refresh UI, etc.
            afterWrite?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    return rowsWritten;
}

I'm sure there are other ways to optimize this - e.g., using some Linq magic to create the batches instead of adding every item to a list. Any suggestions are welcome!

Isn't your need to constantly write data into a database? Why do you need to care about the size of the list?

@shingo Writing each row one at a time performs exceptionally worse than writing a large batch at once

This question is similar to: Find size of object instance in bytes in c#. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Do you acutally need to write 10k~1m rows into db together during business process or is it just a performance testing? i.e. is there actual requirement for such scale?

@PekoMiko It's part of a business process. I've got enormous CSV files generated daily.
From those files, I calculate various things from their contents (those things are what are being written to the database). truncate the database tables, then re-add all the things every night or several times through the day. (In this case, every single db row is invalid after "new things are calculated", so no sense in updating existing rows).
The database operates like a cache that can be effectively queried from the front end for fast reporting. Its contents are too large to fit in memory.

I'd also recommend to have different methods for each concern. For example one for batching, one for the bulk write.

"truncate the database, then re-enter all items" isn't the running application severely affected during the update?

@Fildor IProgressReporter in the example is a wrapper around IProgress that adds additional functionality for throttling, creating messages, calculating percentages, etc. Is there a better way to fix this (not sure what you're saying should be fixed).
What's an alternative to using the enumerator... or are you saying, instead of checking for last, extract the write method & call that again after the loop on source completes if the source had at least one item?

If you care so much about performance, then I'd first fix reporting (use IProgress) and then fix using runtime reflection as well as casting. Also, the use of the enumerator seems odd to me. Not- nots are really confusing.

from csv is important info because file reading can be streams. for example, read only 100 rows from csv per iteration and do write once, repeat until no more rows. That way memory usage can be decreased.

@PekoMiko that's only possible if lines do not possibly depend on each other, though. If they do, it gets more complicated.

@PekoMiko Currently, the CSV file yields an AsyncEnumerable (using the CsvHelper library). Would batching row reads likely improve memory/performance enough to make the added complexity worth it? I was under the impression that the AsyncEnumerable would only keep yielded items around as long as they're needed, eliminating the need for batching.

@Fildor per truncating the database - yes, severely affected, but it's the only thing it does at the time and can't think of a better way.  Often I'll just leave it on overnight to do the job.

@Fildor per "then fix using runtime reflection as well as casting", unfortunately the cast is required, I think (the properties have to cast to objects for the "WriteToServerAsync" method to accept them, and I don't have control over that method).
For reflection, only alternative would be to explicitly specify every property to the method I believe? In this case, the reflection/writing part only happens once every 10-15 seconds at best, so my guess was the tiny performance impact is probably better than the added complexity of not using reflection in every method that calls this extension.

Well, maybe there's a better way. Depending on the actual dbms in use. You could build a second table and on finish "switch" the table name in the app, then drop the old one. Or build and switch the complete database. If it's connected via network maybe even just switch routes.

Do i understand correctly that from the app's perspective it's read-only?

@Fildor Interesting idea. The DBMS is ClickHouse, running locally on WSL. This may eventually move to a remote server. Main problem I could see with this approach is that it (Clickhouse) does hog quite a bit of memory, (but less than holding all its items in the application's memory), so having two copies of these tables (there's multiple giant tables) might run out of memory. Also worth mentioning, the app is essentially useless before I start generating the new items written - it needs the most up-to-date data - so don't really need to have a usable app while these items are being generated.

@Fildor Essentially, yes. For a more complete picture (1) I'm running through market data and generating futures trades based on strategies (very expensive, takes a day or so), (2) from those trades, generating statistics in a variety of ways with trade history (expensive, takes hours) (3) those statistics are written to the ClickHouse database, (4) once statistics are written, a WinUI3 application offers a variety of graphs, tables, etc. to browse and analyze the statistics. #4 is the part where things being very fast is critical, hence all the upfront generation (which can happen overnight)

As to the reflection: if you cannot or don't want to get rid of it completely, I'd move it to application startup. Do it there and keep the result in a lookup by type. It's a micro optimization, but well... could add up.

What's impacting memory though would be strings. Avoid creating many different strings. So maybe also think about reporting. Does it need to be that detailed? Does it need to create and pass around different strings?

@Fildor per reflection, I added an option to pass in a mapper that can create the object property array without needing reflection - good point.
Per reporting, I - think - the string only gets created when the function is actually called (once every 500ms in this case; internally it only executes the function when Datetime.Now is greater than last reported time + interval). Not 100% sure that assumption is true, or if passing in the function is more expensive.

I assume T is always a class and not a struct?

I think one of the issues in our specific case is that we are not sure of how the IAsyncEnumerable<T> is internally implemented.
Thus even if we do our part in batch.Clear() to zero the references in the underlying array so to not keep the objects alive, the implementation of IAsyncEnumerable<T> might still reference those elements in one of its internal data structures.
For example:
async Task Main() {
    var asyncImplementation = new AsyncEnumerableImplmenetation();
    await ConsumeIAsyncEnumerable(asyncImplementation.GetAsyncEnumerable());
}

public async Task ConsumeIAsyncEnumerable<T>(IAsyncEnumerable<T> asyncEnumerable) {
    var list = new List<T>();
    var listWeakHandle = new List<WeakReference>();
    await foreach (var element in asyncEnumerable) {
        list.Add(element);
        listWeakHandle.Add(new WeakReference(element));
    }

    list.Clear();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    var stilLReferencedElements = listWeakHandle.Where(x => x.IsAlive).Count();
    Console.WriteLine(stilLReferencedElements); // 100

}

public class A { }


public class AsyncEnumerableImplmenetation {
    public A[] _backingStore = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                .Select(x => new A())
                .ToArray();

    public async IAsyncEnumerable<A> GetAsyncEnumerable() {
        for (int i = 0; i < _backingStore.Length; i++) {
            await Task.Delay(1); // optional
            yield return _backingStore[i];
            //_backingStore[i] = null; // clear the element for GC
        }
    }
}

That's why it might make sense to investigate this possibility in your special case with the CsvHelper library using the above approach. Run the whole IAsyncEnumerable<T> and see if the library is keeping everything alive or it's also internally batching to a certain number of objects.
If it's the first case - nothing we do will really help reduce the memory.
If it's the second case (which is much more likely) - then you can rely on some of the solutions from this question - preferably investigating the logic in the library used in this answer. This is until there is an official API - which from the looks of this issue isn't promising. Still this comment from it can help you:

there are ways to not have GC do this - you could do this via
debugging APIs (ICorDebugProcess5::GetTypeLayout and related),
profiling APIs (similar to debugging ones) or reflection (you could
get the fields of an object and calculate the size of each). not to
say these are easy to do or don't have their own set of problems - for
example, if you use the debugging/profiling APIs you can't attach
another live debugger/profiler to the same process.

Or as a more general bur error-prone approach we can incorporate GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes() calls into the "batch size determining" logic with the obvious caveat that it's not precise (but might be fast enough?) and will count bytes being allocated in other parts of the application at this time. Once a certain delta threshold (the batch size) is reached this could trigger the batch.Clear() and the bulk copy operation.

Interesting, hadn't considered that. Worth mentioning that a not-rigorous approach of watching memory in Task Manager suggests that the second case is more likely. Memory starts low, climbs, then suddenly drops (when batches get cleared), and seems to gradually decrease as time goes on (async enumerable items source items remove from memory, is my assumption)

As far as the original question of getting memory - was hoping there was an easy API for it. Your answer on a solution is great, I'll mark it as the answer... although I think I'll leave this as a "nice-to-have" on the to-do list and come back later (seems like the workarounds you mentioned could open up a rabbit hole of new potential issues that I don't have time to handle right now!). Thank you for the help!

@Sean yeah, the best way would be if Microsoft gave us the API themselves. Otherwise almost all third party solutions could become obsolete if they rely on internal implementation details (which I think they kind of have to speed things up) + handling of collections, cyclical dependencies etc.

There is no really easy and performant way to calculate the exact size BUT here is a list of potential solutions:

Since you are reading a CSV file, your CSV reader should expose an information about the last cursor position. Knowing a typical row structure (number of ints, strings, dates), you can approximately calculate the size of the created .NET objects. You say that 20% deviation is not an issue, then this approach will work for sure.
As an alternative you can implement a custom size calculation logic directly in the DTO and simply sum up the numbers.
Since your memory is allocated on the heap, you can use GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes or GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread methods to calculate the number of allocated bytes between every 1000nd reads. Of course, the number is not equal the size of your list BUT will be within your desired 20% error.


#1 seems like it could work in many cases, someone will find it useful. Unfortunately, in my case, the items read from CSV are then grouped, then hundreds of objects that vary in size are created from each row, and - that - result is the one I'd have to monitor for size. Similar issue for #2 probably. #3 seems to be the only possible solution, although I'm wary of what new problems it could introduce, so might just stick with fine-tuning the numbers for now to keep dev momentum up. Thanks!

@Sean Sorry, I don't understand why #1 won't work for you. It doesn't matter how many objects are created from one row (unless they are not objects with one-three fields). Lets say your CSV line has 50 integers and 10 string fields. You definitely know that 50 integers will take 200 bytes. String size may vary but you can easily calculate total size of all strings. Then there is 12 bytes overhead per instantiated object, take 20-30 objects as an average count. Simple math 200(=50x4)+strings_size+20x12=~row_size_in_net_memory. Definitely not precise but 1GB precision guaranteed )))

@Sean with an access to CsvReader instance, a bit of approximation and reflection you could easily come as close as 10% to the correct answer.
